# Make debuggr spit out YES/NO instead of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c

this might be a trivial question but im writing some categories for iOS and one of them is for NSString. and when comparing to apples method, my return value is different

In the debugger, apples methods return `YES`/`NO`

`po [@"hello world" containsString:@"wo"]` returns `YES`

`po [@"hello world" containsString:@"wof"]` returns `NO`

however, on my categories, i get `0x0000000000000001`/`0x0000000000000000`/`nil`

`po [@"hello world" mn_hasText]` returns `0x0000000000000001`

`po [@"   " mn_hasText]` returns `nil`

Heres my code

```
- (NSString *)mn_removeWhiteSpace {
    return [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}


- (BOOL)mn_hasText{
    return ([self mn_removeWhiteSpace].length == 0) ? NO : YES;
}
```

How do i get the debugger to spit out `YES`/`NO`

Edit: to clarify, i want to replicate the debugger spitting out YES/NO rather than memory addresses when using `po`. Its mostly a user preference thing, but id perfer to log YES/NO.

Comment: have you tried using p (print) instead of po (print-object)?

Comment: should that matter? im using `PO` on apples `containsString:` which returns `YES`. i want to replicate that

Comment: with `p` i get `error: no known method '-mn_hasText'; cast the message send to the method's return type`. i shouldnt have to cast it to `(BOOL)`

Comment: You are correct that "it should not matter". It's just that sometimes you can find a bug that makes no sense and loose hours on figuring it out. I'd try subclassing instead of using category next... just to make sure it is not a debuger+category issue.

Comment: And do you have BOOL instead of bool declaration in both (.h and .m) of your category? It might seem pointless but they are actually not the same type.

Comment: @RokJarc yes, i've changed both .m and .h to `BOOL` from `bool` after reading @zepar comment. ill try subclassing to see if anything changes, but thats not the route i want to go.

Comment: Could you use NSLog? `NSLog(flag ? @"Yes" : @"No");`

Answer (score 0):

"po" means print object.  To print a scalar type, use "p"....

```
BOOL foo = YES;
```

[image]

Comment: like i said, this is probably trivial but id like to replicate apples return type with bools. doing `po [@"hello world" containsString:@"wo"]` spits out YES/NO. i want the same output from my categories